# 2 Probability Question

Tags: probability

There are 9 wrapping bags, 3 of which contains 2GB pen drive, and the rest contains 1 GB Pendrive. There are 3 girls and 5 boys randomly select a bag each. Find the probability that

i) the girls select more bags which contains 2GB pendrive than the boys
ii) none of the girls has a bag which contain 2GB pendrive

Just wanna make sure, for

i) is it P(X more and equal to 2) where n=3, r=2 & 3 respectively, p=1/3 while q=2/3

ii) is it P(X=O) whr n=3, r=0, p=2/3, q=1/3 ?

Comment: Ahh my bad, it's supposed to be 2GB instead of 3GB. Sorry

Comment: To your question:  it looks like you are treating this like a binomial distribution, but that isn't right since (presumably) the kids choose without replacement.  Thus, while the first kid has a $\frac 13$ chance of drawing a 2GB drive, the second kid's chances depend on what the first kid drew.

Comment: Hint:  go case by case:  what is the probability that the girls draw exactly two?  what is the probability that they draw three?

Comment: Hint 2: probability functions for Hypergeometric distributions involve binomial coefficients, re: The probability for selection of $k$ from $K$ 'successes" and $(n-k)$ from $(N-K)$ "failures" when selecting and $n$ from $N$ items.

Comment: What is n-K ? ^^;; 
I'm sorry but my Statistic knowledge and understanding are very basic...as  I'm also learning the basic Stats only ^^;;